# How do I make it so editing one key automatically update the other icon-related keys in the registry?

Tags: registry

I noticed when I set an icon with [Gunners File Type Editor](https://www.gunnerinc.com/gfte.htm), it produces 4 in total keys.

[image]

If I change the the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\011File\DefaultIcon string (using RegEdit), it automatically creates/updates the other 3 other keys. This is not the usual behaviour. How can I replicate this behaviour without using Gunners File Type Editor?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this behaviour only occurs if the file is not associated with an application by default. To restore it to this behaviour, the `UserChoice` key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.file_extension_name` must bE deleted.